# Common Lisp: getting all keys of a given hash table as a list

Tags: lisp, hashmap, hashtable, common-lisp, key

I wonder if there is a less verbose way than using a loop. Anyway this works for me in CLISP:

```
(loop for key being the hash-keys of *my-hash* collect key)
```

I've seen others using `maphash`, but that involves accumulating each key into a list. Apart from that being more involved than using loop, it also introduces a side-effect, which I try to avoid whenever I can - I prefer functional programming as much as possible :)

Is there anything predefined like this for this common task, even though implementation-specific?

```
(defun hash-keys (hash-table)
  (loop for key being the hash-keys of hash-table collect key))
```

Answer (score 22):

Common Lisp comes from before "batteries-included" philosophy became prevalent, and most functionality is expected to be provided by third-party libraries and not implementations. While Common Lisp is sometimes called a large language, it is only compared to C and similar, the language itself is quite tiny compared to Python and other languages with massive standard libraries.

For this specific purpose, [Alexandria](http://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/) is a commonly used collection of Common Lisp utilities. Among many other things it contains `hash-table-keys`.

Comment: Common Lisp was very much "batteries included" for its time. People just expect way more (and different kinds of) batteries now.

Comment: Common Lisp is only slightly large now compared to C, which is now pushing close to 700 pages of ISO standard. (And is only a slightly more "batteries included" language than it was in 1989 when it was 200-something pages.)

Comment: Most "batteries included" languages that are popular these days **have** to be that way, because functions that you write yourself have a performance disadvantage.

Comment: how unfortunate; lisp could be ruling the world by just ripping the features it needs from other runtimes which are always lisp clones. There's no reason lisp can't talk to nodejs or perl or bash and use their libraries, or just access their runtimes directly.

Comment: I know nothing of Python or Ruby etc. But compared to OCAML or Haskell or Julia, the Common Lisp batteries are quite impressive. It is one of the few languages out there, where you can get something basic done without wading through the "library swamp".

Answer (score 17):

There is no disadvantage in defining

```
(defun hash-keys (hash-table)
  (loop for key being the hash-keys of hash-table collect key))
```

because in Common Lisp the function is compiled. If your vendor provided this function, it would pretty much do the same thing and not be much more efficient than yours, if at all.

In interpreted languages, nearly anything you write yourself has a performance disadvantage compared to an "intrinsic" routine.

Consing up the contents of a hash is wasteful; loop lets you process the hash without consing up memory. So maybe you want a macro instead (Some Lisps provide a `dohash` or similar as an extension).

```
(defmacro do-hash ((key-var val-var hash-expr &optional result-form) &body body)
  (let ((hash-var (gensym "HASH-")))
     `(loop with ,hash-var = ,hash-expr
            for ,key-var being the hash-keys of ,hash-var
            for ,val-var being the hash-values of ,hash-var
            do (progn ,@body)
            finally (return ,result-form))))
```

Or a hash mapping function:

```
 (defun mapc-hash (hash-table fun) 
   (loop for key being the hash-keys of hash-table
         for value being the hash-values of hash-table
         do (funcall fun key value)))
```

Should the language have every possible gadget like this that anyone can write in a minute?

In Common Lisp, there are included batteries, but they are other kinds of batteries: things that are actually hard to do. For example, a `compile` function for dynamically compiling code at run time. It would be prohibitively difficult for most users to develop such a thing from scratch compared to pulling keys or values from a hash table in half a dozen different ways.

Comment: (not to mention the macro definition facilities that you showcase here as well... :) ).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it does not depend on an external library

Comment: Reinvented wheel :) `(maphash #'(lambda (key value) ...) ht)` is one of CL's batteries :)

Comment: @BitTickler **It gets funnier**. This answer was in March 2012, as can be plainly seen. In  [November 2011 I added `maphash`](https://www.kylheku.com/cgit/txr/commit/?id=4c4666476b3e3b8d24a001416537f1a3e3146d41) with the same conventions to TXR Lisp.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use it more than once, the less lengthy solution is, to write yourself a very short helper function:

```
(defun hash-table-keys (ht)
  (let ((keys nil))
    (maphash
     #'(lambda (k v)
         (declare (ignore v))
         (push k keys))
     ht)
    keys))
```

As you can see and as other answers have also pointed out, in many cases, it is easier to iterate all entries of a hash table, rather than constructing a filtered list and then iterating over that one.

Using the standard Common Lisp function `maphash` is useful in both scenarios.